# Invalid pipe to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to test using rtmpdump and piping that to ffmpeg, then to a new rtmp destination.

I am testing using unprotected rtmp source for now, to make it easy.  I try to pipe to ffmpeg and I get the error. "pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input"

Here is my code, can you see where the issue is? Thanks so much.

```
C:\livestreamer\rtmpdump\rtmpdump.exe -r "rtmp://176.36.121.6/live/LIVETV/UNIVERSAL_FL" -q | C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i - -isync -acodec aac -strict -2 -ab 48000 -ar 48000 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -s 690x430 -b:v 400k -b:a 20k -ar 32000 -ac 1 -f flv "rtmp://rtmp.goodcast.pw:1935/liverepeater/162226"
```

Edit: This 'goodcast' rtmp server in example is open for testing purpose if you want to test using that.  To view any test, the url = http://goodcast.me/stream.php?id=162226

Comment: `ffmpeg` can accept [RTMP protocol as input](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtmp). Why not just use `ffmpeg`?